# Ruby on Rails + Filemaker Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, filemaker

I want to use RoR to interact with data stored in a Filemaker Database. I've looked at RFM and tried reading trough the documentation, but it's really elaborate and demands a certain knowledge about Filemaker (which I do not possess). Could anyone explain the basics of a FM database, and how RFM (ginjo) works? If possible, a reference app would be perfect.

Many thanks!
T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm aware that my question was rather lacking, and kinda bad. After some time invested in it, I've come up with a solution. If anyone sees this and has a similar question, don't hesitate to PM or send me an email.

Thanks!

Comment: Can your share your solution?
We also have a need to bridge the Filemaker and RoR worlds.

Comment: You can try the RFM gem - https://github.com/lardawge/rfm - but the easiest solution would be just to sync your mysql database with FileMaker using this: http://360works.com/filemaker-sync/